# javascript - google maps boundaries with overlapping shapes

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm having an issue with drawing points on the map and having the inside of the points be transparent. It works perfectly if the shape has no overlapping points, but as you can see in this example there is a triangle and a square and they overlap, and only one shape has the `fillOpacity` set to 0..

[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
MapPoll.prototype._redrawBoundaries = function () {
    var allWorld = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(85, 180),
        new google.maps.LatLng(85, 90),
        new google.maps.LatLng(85, 0),
        new google.maps.LatLng(85, -90),
        new google.maps.LatLng(85, -180),
        new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -90),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 0),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 90),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 180),
        new google.maps.LatLng(0, 180),
        new google.maps.LatLng(85, 180)
    ];

    this.map.data.setStyle({
        cursor: "not-allowed",
        fillColor: "#000000",
        fillOpacity: this._showBoundaries ? 0.25 : 0,
        strokeWeight: 1
    });
    if (this._boundaries.length > 0) {
        this._boundariesPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: this._boundaries });

        console.log(this._boundaries)

    this.map.data.add({
        geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([allWorld, this._boundaries])
    });
    }
    else {
        this._boundariesPolygon = null;
    }

};
```

and `this._boundaries` is a list of points that looks like this:

```
0: {lat: 36.032487228417146, lng: -78.83335640047085}
1: {lat: 36.036929334756095, lng: -78.88279487703335}
2: {lat: 36.24542550544885, lng: -78.84983589265835}
3: {lat: 35.66738312535577, lng: -78.85532905672085}
4: {lat: 35.63167328632597, lng: -78.27854683015835}
5: {lat: 36.010272939034245, lng: -78.21262886140835}
6: {lat: 36.041371190553185, lng: -78.84983589265835}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? It's really frustrating, and seems like it should work! Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like filling of self-intersecting polygons are not supported in Google Maps API. I can see several issues in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827672, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823994.